# C# Append lines to `*.docx` file produced from `*.dotx` file

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using this code to produce a `*.docx` file from a `*.dotx` template file:

**Create Document from template and replace words:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat1", "replaced1");
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat2", "replaced2");

File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    // Change the document's type here
    wordDoc.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    string docText = null;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in keyValues)
    {
        Regex regexText = new Regex(item.Key);
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, item.Value);
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
    wordDoc.Close();
}
```

In another function I am trying to append some lines to the `*.docx` file:

**Append Lines:**

```
foreach (var user in usersApproved)
                     File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(("..\\Files\\TFFiles\\" + tid + "\\" + file.SiteId + "\\" + file.Type + "\\")) + Path.GetFileName(file.Title), "Document Signed by: " + user.UserName + Environment.NewLine);
```

But I get this error:

> Signature append failed:The process cannot access the file
>   '(path)\destinationFile.docx' because it is being used by
>   another process.

Tried also this solution : [OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx) but Im getting the same error

Comment: This came up in another question you cant just append text to the docx file.

Comment: @BugFinder is there another way then?

Comment: As described in the solution you linked: create a new Paragraph, create a new Run with your text, append the run to the Paragraph, append the paragraph to the body. Don't use the StreamWriter, save the changed document instead.

Comment: @LocEngineer can you provide a runnable example based on my code? I cant make it work

Comment: Note: I haven't touched the `Server.MapPath` part of your code. Are you trying to run this from within asp.net? If so you might run into other problems still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would replace text using your Dictionary of Regexes and replacements:

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat1", "replaced1");
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat2", "replaced2");

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    // Change the document's type here
    wordDoc.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    foreach (Run rText in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>())
    {
        foreach (var text in rText.Elements<Text>())
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in keyValues)
            {
                Regex regexText = new Regex(item.Key);
                text.Text = regexText.Replace(text.Text, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    wordDoc.Save();
}
```

And this is how you would append text:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    var para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
    var run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

    var txt = "Document Signed by: LocEngineer";
    run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
    wordDoc.Save();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to append the text in another function. The function with the replace stuff is creating the document from a template. After that the user can open the document and approve it and if user approves the document then I want to append a line that this user signed that document

Comment: So what? Then simply leave that `foreach` out of this code and use it in the other. Where's the problem?

Comment: I should take the `"var para .... run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));"` lines and put them in the function where user signs the document. But when I create and replace words in the document I can't use wordDoc.Save()  (error doesnt contain a definition....) . Should I use .Close() ? And then when I append the line in the document should I use .Close() again?

Comment: `when I create and replace words in the document` HOW are you doing that? Please update the code in your question to reflect your current situation and where the error occurs. I would bet hard money you still aren't doing it correctly.

Comment: Take a look at my updated post. The first code snippet is part from the code where I open the template file, create the document file and then replace the words inside it. The second code snippet is from another function where I want to append the lines.

Comment: Your updated code is still the completely wrong thing. You cannot change or append text like this. You need to iterate over the `Run`s and change *their* text or create and append a new paragraph with a run containing the new text, just as described in my example above.

Comment: Split the code in two parts, for replacing text and for appending.